# Animated 2D Histogram

Tags: python, video, plot, histogram, diagram

I am not sure if what I want is possible to do. I did not find a solution yet.
I have data, that I can display with the hist2d of Matplotlib.
Is there a way to render a video/animation of many (!) of these histograms out of a list of lists?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stackoverflow. I would imagine that you have a way of calculating the distributions at different times, yes? How about having a look at [matplotlib.animation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/animation_api.html)

Comment: I do not calculate the histograms. The data is already there. I would arrange the data in a list of lists, in which every list contains one frame of the animation.

Comment: In which case you may want to walk through the list and paint each frame using `pyplot.hist`. Have a look at the example at the end of the link I referenced.

Comment: Thank you. I have seen it, but I don't get it completely. I expect to plot every frame separatly and append it to the video. But I can't see that in the example.

Comment: No. You don't actually create a collection of frames. Instead you do it as one would in a GUI application. Think of it more like a `map`, you pass it in the list of data, and you tell how to paint the data on screen. What you need to do in this case is to  write a function `paint_frame` that takes an element of the list of lists, and paints it. Then pass it to `FuncAnimation`. Let me know if that's not enough so I can provide you with an example.

Comment: A simplistic example would be appreciated, if it doesn't take too much time. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of how to do it. If you don't want the previous plots to get gone after each frame you should remove the `ax.clear()` call.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]]


def plot(frame):
    ax.clear()
    ax.hist(frame)

# blit=True may be helpful if you're using plt.plot() directly. 

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, plot, frames=data, blit=False)
plt.show()
```